# Most recent output in Colab notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory

I forgot to get the history *histrory = model.fit( ...)* trained for 2 hours and my cell look like this:

```
model.fit( ....)
```

Is there a variable (as in matlab's "ans"), for the most recent output?

I tried output, out, out[-1], etc. None of the work.

Any help or workarounds would be appreciated.

CS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The global dictionary `Out` holds all cell outputs. So, for example, if you executed the code in cell 20, `Out[20]` has the result.

You can also get the output of the most recent execution with the `_` variable.

Comment: So that is Out with O in caps! almost guessed it right! Awesome. It would be great, if you could give me a reference!!

Comment: See https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.04-input-output-history.html

Comment: @jakevdp Do you plan to update the book to use Altair or Plotly instead of MLP?